# Make duplicate ids unique using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have html files that are auto-generated from a process. Unfortunately, that process creates some `div` with duplicated id's. Is there a way to convert these id's into unique id's by adding an integer at the end?

I can't remove or hide those `div's.

Comment: Sounds possible. I suggest giving it a try and showing us where you get stuck.

Comment: u try - we try...

Comment: Instead of trying to fix the problem with JS later, why not fix the issue at the source? Generating duplicate IDs is a no-no anyway. Moreover, the browser's JS engine behaviour when encountering multiple instances of the same ID is officially defined as "undefined", meaning that you will not, and cannot, ensure that the same JS function **can and will consistantly** identify all duplicate IDs and fix them across all browsers.

Comment: Yes, this is entirely possible. but you should first explore the idea of fixing the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's certainly possible, you get use `.each()` and select the elements by their `id` attribute:

```js
$("div[id='foo']").each(function(i){
    $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id') + i);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">test</div>
<div id="foo">test</div>
<div id="foo">test</div>
```

This will change the HTML to:

```
<div id="foo0">test</div>
<div id="foo1">test</div>
<div id="foo2">test</div>
```

Comment: This helped. Thanks a lot.